# Why? Did Allah choose Isa(Jesus)(as) out of all the other prophets to be born a miracle? And choose him to come back before day of judgment?

Tags: prophet-isa, dawah

I usually have debates with my mum who is a hard core Christian and every time I tell her that Muhammad(pbuh) is the best of all creation she tells me 'then why did god choose Jesus(as) out of all the prophet to be born a miracle and choose him to come back at the end of times?'.

Comment: This is a logical fallacy. She could as well ask "Why did God choose you to be her son out of 7 billion people?". Miracles are given by Allah, and we don't question them. Being born without father does not imply _betterness_ of one (Jesus pbuh) over the other (Muhammad pbuh). Same for coming back at the end of times. Those are miracles given by the Creator, not of the creation's achievement. So one should look at the source and give credit where it's due.

Comment: Although I don't know the answer to this, it still makes more sense to send Jesus (A.S.) back to earth instead of any other prophet, given that Christianity is the most corrupt of the 3 Abrahamic religions. This could be one of the reasons. But Allah knows best.

Comment: Here are some thoughts, in case you find them useful. Note that God constantly referred to the Jews as "stiff-necked", that is, rebellious. And he sent many, many prophets that the Jews rarely listened to. Perhaps the miraculous birth of Jesus was a more vigorous means of getting them to listen? As for Jesus being highly honored, perhaps it is for similar reasons: perhaps God is doing it in order to make the point that the Jews should have listened to a guy who was born miraculously.

Answer (score 3):

This question is like asking why did Allah create Adam before Muhammad s.a.w: This is because He is the creator and He does whatever He wills.

Comment: Salam and Welcome on Islam SE. Please consider taking your time and take our [tour] visit our [help] to learn more about the site and model. We are not an internet forum therefore this is not an answer as we expect here, so please read [answer] to learn what we expect here for good answers. I think almost all of us agree that Allah knows best! But we are asked to use our mind ...

Answer (score 0):

Allah used to send prophet and gave them miracles according to the need of time. Hazrat Muhammad (PBUH) was sent at the time when the Arabs were too much interested in poetry and the best poet's work was hanged at Kaaba. So our Holy Prophet was give the Quran and despite many challenges the non-believers failed to produce any surah like the smallest one in Quran. Hazrat Musa (Alaih-Salam) was given the miracle of Hand and wooden log as this was the time of witchcraft. Hazrat Isa'(Alaih-Salam) was born at the time when there was prevalent the eastern medical knowledge (So-called TIB). This is my humble opinion and real knowledge is with the Almighty.

Answer (score 0):

When you consider the many prophets who were slain by the jews and their general attitude towards prophets, the lack of respect and constant challenges directed at them , ie. Accusations thst they are just magicians soothsayers and the consistently obstinate nature of the jews, especially the levites and leadership amongst them( pharisees, saducees :sanhedrin). It seems God decided to send a prophet who they would have to take seriously, as a baby who can speak, born of 1 of the, if not 'The' most, noblest of families aswell as being extremely pious and being of a pure and innocent character and disposition. You could not simply call this child a magician, who is obviously from amongst your own, and from the best at that, whose cousin Yahya( john the baptist) PBUH was a prophet and if the jews did not believe that they certainly knew and know him and his father Zechariah (PBUH who was also a prophet) as being very pious and righteous persons. This was in effect Gods final message as well as warning, the severity of which is blatantly outlined by God sending a prophet whose credentials can in no way be doubted, affirmed by yahya, zechariah and the pious and temple servant maryam(mary) his mother.
The 2nd reason i believe is that after coming back from babylonian exile, brought back by cyrus. The jews established a law that was and still is 1 of the most baffling and revolutionary jewish laws ever, going against the god given methods for recording ones ancestry and genealogy. The jews from the persian period onwards declared that you were a jew, ie.you could inherit your righteous jewish soul, as long as your mother is a jew, regardless of who your father is. So it was now matrilineal not patrilineal n in israel today if your father is a jew but not your mother your not considered jew, and are a 2nd tier or class jew! So when jesus was born to mary who is from the davidic line, which is the main pre-requisite to be acknowledged as the messiah, and born to Only a woman, a pious woman from noble davidic stock, it was as if God was testing them! It was a means for the jews to control the membership of who can join their special israelite family, as daughters and who they marry are far essier to control than controlling your sons and who they marry and who they simply have extra marital relations with that more oft than not result in children who are now technically israelites, just like the Samaritans who were of this category of jews.
So it was God probably saying "ok, you changed the law, then lets see how you like your messiah who has not jewish father only a jewish mother who by your law carries the collective spirit of israel". The jews made more laws like for the levites and their kohanims or cohen, ie. Priests from the tribe of levi, to be considered a righteous cohen both your parents must be jews, however the messiah doesnt fit in that law as he would not be from the tribe of levi but the tribe of david.
Hope that helps, salam

Answer (score -1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

Indeed Prophets show different Miracles as a sign for those who could understand, This beautiful Hadith shows that Every Prophets are Higher in Status and as you stated Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him is not only the best of all  creation but also the most beloved of Allah Swt,

> Narrated Ibn 'Abbas: that a group of people from the Companions of the
>   Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) sat waiting for him. He said: "Then he came
>   out, such that when he came close to them, he heard them talking, and
>   he heard what they were saying. So some of them said: 'It's amazing
>   that Allah, the Mighty and Sublime, has taken a Khalil (close friend)
>   from His creation. He took Ibrahim as a Khalil.' And some of them
>   said: 'That is not more amazing than speaking to Musa, He spoke to him
>   with real speech.' And some said: 'And 'Eisa is the word of Allah and
>   His Spirit.' And some said: 'Adam was chosen by Allah.' So he (ﷺ) came
>   out upon them and said his Salam, and said: 'I have heard your words,
>   and your amazement that Ibrahim is the Khalil of Allah, and he is
>   such, and that Musa is the one spoken to by Allah, and he is such, and
>   that 'Eisa is the spirit of Allah and His Word, and he is such, and
>   that Adam was chosen by Allah, and he is such. **Indeed I am the beloved
>   of Allah and I am not boasting, and I am the carrier of the Banner of
>   Praise on the Day of Judgement, and I am not boasting. And I am the
>   first intercessor, and the first to have intercession accepted from
>   him on the Day of Judgement, and I am not boasting. And I am the first
>   to shake the rings of Paradise (meaning on the gates of Paradise) and
>   so Allah will open it for me and admit me into it. And with me will be
>   the poor people from the believers, and I am not boasting. And I am
>   the most noble among the first ones and the last ones, and I am not
>   boasting."**(Tirmidhi)

And Allah Swt says in Quran

> وَإِنَّهُ لَعِلْمٌ لِّلسَّاعَةِ فَلَا تَمْتَرُنَّ بِهَا وَاتَّبِعُونِ
>   ۚ هَـٰذَا صِرَاطٌ مُّسْتَقِيمٌ
>
> And indeed Eisa is a sign* of the Last Day, therefore do not ever
>   doubt in the Last Day, and obey Me**; this is the Straight Path. (*
>   The advent of Prophet Eisa to earth for the second time. ** By obeying
>   the Noble Messenger.)([Quran 43:61](http://tanzil.net/#43:61))

Prophet Isa peace be upon him is one of the sign of the End of times.He will come back in the end of times and how amazing it is that he would come as an Ummati of beloved Prophet peace be upon him,he will follow Shariah of Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him and spread his teachings.

There is a narration and it is said that Prophet Isa peace be upon him wished to become ummati of prophet Muhammad peace be upon him after one incident which is mentioned in Nuzhat ul majalis.

> Once Prophet Isa peace be upon him passed by a luminous mountain that
>   was sparkling with light. He said to Allah 'O Allah! Bless this
>   mountain with the power to speak.The mountain spoke and said, 'O
>   RoohAllah What do you desire?' He replied, Tell me your state.' The
>   mountain said, A person lives inside me.Prophet Isa peace be upon him
>   said to Allah,Allow me to see him,The mountain split open and a very
>   handsome  pious man emerged from it. This pious man said, I am the
>   follower of prophet Musa peace be upon him. I supplicated to Allah
>   that He let me live until the time of His beloved Messenger SallAllahu
>   Alaihi wa Sallam so that I may have the honour of seeing him and also
>   be privileged of becoming his follower. Alhamdu-Lillah! I have been
>   busy worshipping Allah inside this mountain for 600 years.Prophet Isa
>   peace be upon him asked Allah, O Allah Is there anyone on this earth
>   dearer to you than this person? Allah answered: 'O Isa! Whoever from
>   the Ummah of Muhammad fasts for a single day in the month of Rajab, is
>   dearer to me than this person.' [Nuzha-tul-Majaalis, Vol. 1, Page 155]

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: This does not answer the question, rather merely reiterates the fact mentioned in the OP :'(